# _ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv trying to import C++ code in Python after compiling shared object

Tags: python, c++, arrays, g++, shared-libraries

Run into a frustrating issue trying to import a Python library that itself calls some code I wrote in C++ and compiled into a .so

The C++ code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>

std::vector<std::string> bigram(std::string initial_str) {
    int len = initial_str.size();
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i += 1){
        tokens.push_back(initial_str.substr(i, 2));
    }
    return tokens;
}

std::vector<std::string> vsunion(std::vector<std::string> s1, std::vector<std::string> s2) {
    std::vector<std::string> union_str(s1);
    union_str.insert(union_str.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end());
    std::sort(union_str.begin(), union_str.end());
    union_str.erase(std::unique(union_str.begin(), union_str.end()), union_str.end());
    return union_str;
}

std::vector<int> ufreq(std::vector<std::string> u, std::vector<std::string> s) {
    int len = u.size();
    std::vector<int> vfreq;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 1){
        int freq = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), u[i]);
        vfreq.push_back(freq);
    }
    return vfreq;
}

float similarity(std::vector<int> f1, std::vector<int> f2) {
    float num = std::inner_product(f1.begin(), f1.end(), f2.begin(), 0.0);
    float den1 = std::inner_product(f1.begin(), f1.end(), f1.begin(), 0.0);
    float den2 = std::inner_product(f2.begin(), f2.end(), f2.begin(), 0.0);
    float similarity = num / std::sqrt(den1 * den2);
    return similarity;
}

float similarity(std::string string1, std::string string2) {
    std::vector<std::string> new_str = bigram(string1);
    std::vector<std::string> new_str2 = bigram(string2);
    std::vector<std::string> union_str = vsunion(new_str, new_str2);
    std::vector<int> freq1 = ufreq(union_str, new_str);
    std::vector<int> freq2 = ufreq(union_str, new_str2);
    float score = similarity(freq1, freq2);
    return score;
}

extern "C" {
    float gram(std::string str1, std::string str2)
    {
        return similarity(str1, str2);
    }
}
```

Which I compiled using:

```
g++ gram.cpp -shared -o gram.so
```

and finally I'm trying to import the below script that's throwing the error in the title "_ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv could not be located in the dynamic link library":

```
import ctypes
import sys
import os 

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
handle = ctypes.CDLL(dir_path + "/gram.so")

handle.My_Function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p] 
  
def gram(string1, string2):
    return handle.gram(string1, string2)
```

Any idea where I might have gone wrong?  I can compile a test case instead of the "extern" bit:

```
int main() {
    float score = similarity("John Smith", "Johnny John Smith");
    std::cout << score << " ";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

and run as an exe, seemingly without issue; something seems to be going wrong at the

```
handle = ctypes.CDLL(dir_path + "/gram.so")
```

stage in the gram library.

Comment: It looks like python preloaded an older version of libstd++.so. Try `g++ gram.cpp -fpic -static -shared -o gram.so`. And do not forget `-fpic`.

Comment: @273K I suspect that you have _no idea_ of what the implications of linking `gram.so` with the `-static` flag really are. It's a really bad idea(TM).

Answer (score 2):

> finally I'm trying to import the below script that's throwing the error in the title "_ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv could not be located in the dynamic link library":

This error means: the version of `libstdc++.so` available at runtime doesn't have `std::throw_bad_array_new_length` symbol, which your `gram.so` is using.

While it's possible to work around this with `g++ gram.cpp -shared -o gram.so -fPIC -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc`, you really shouldn't -- it will explode in your face sooner or later.

Instead, you should use `Python` which has been linked against `libstdc++.so.6` *appropriate for your system*.

Comment: When you say "Instead, you should use Python", are you saying there's some way for me to load the .cpp directly, rather than compiling into a .so/.dll?  At the moment I've gotten around this issue simply by using Cython and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @hillard28 No, what I am saying is that you should use a _different_  python binary (ome matching your version of `libstdc++.so`. "everything seems to work fine" -- sure. It can break at any moment because you are in undefined territory, but if that's ok with you, who am I to argue.