# throw_bad_array_new_length dll issue with mingw

Tags: gcc, dll, gdb, mingw

**Update 2**

There is a new gcc 10.5 release which doesn't have this problem.
I have contacted Brecht to understand the root cause of this issue.

https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/releases/tag/10.5.0-11.0.1-msvcrt-r2

**Update 1**

As a temporary workaround, I copied gdb.exe, libstdc++-6.dll, libmcfgthread-1.dll and the entire python3.9 folder under lib from the 13.2.0 release. If I find out more about this issue I will post a new update (including the explanation ie. how this problem occured in the first place)

**Original post**

I tried to download GCC 10.5.0 + MinGW-w64 11.0.1 (MSVCRT) from winlibs (https://winlibs.com/) and it seems that there is an issue with gdb only. While I can compile and link just fine, gdb won't start.
The error is "The procedure entry point _zSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv could not be located in the dynamic link library.."

Searching for this issue I stumbled upon
[_ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv trying to import C++ code in Python after compiling shared object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71331756/zst28-throw-bad-array-new-lengthv-trying-to-import-c-code-in-python-after-co)

where it says there's an issue with libstdc++ which doesn't contain the std::throw_bad_array_new_length symbol.

The bin folder does contain a libstdc++-6.dll and when I use a DLL dependency app to view the available library functions I find a single entry which resembles throw_bad_array_new_length but has a different prefix ie. __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length

Can a more experienced developer understand where's the problem coming from? Is it a mistake with how the toolchain was built? Is there a workaround?

[image: dll]

[image: error]

Comment: Have you tried another version, maybe a more recent one?

Comment: actually gcc 10.5 is very recent, launched 7th of July 2023. The problem is that, being a long term support version, comes with msvcrt instead of ucrt like ie. gcc 13. But yes, gcc 13 for instance doesn't have this problem.

Comment: You're right, I missed that this was released not long ago. And I see you already made a [bug report](https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_mingw/issues/168), which was what I would have suggested next. You should be able to use a gdb from another version until this is fixed.

Comment: I managed to "hack" the 10.5 release by copying gdb and 2 of its dependencies from the 13.2.0 release. But this is more of a workaround, I'm really interested in the actual technical reason why the 10.5 gdb was linked the way it is and why the required symbol from libstdc++ isn't there.